# how to stop dbentityentry.currentvalues.setvalues trying to change entitykey value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using the following code to update an entity object with the new information gathered from the my code. I am using **Entity Framework 5**.

I use the following extension method (as a alternative to the reattach code I used to use in EF4):

```
public static void ApplyValues(this object currentObject, object sourceObject, System.Data.Entity.DbContext obj)
{
  obj.Entry(currentObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(sourceObject);
}
```

The problem is that when this method is called the `SetValues` method tries to modify the `EntityKey` value on the attached object (obviously I do not want it to do this) and so it throws an error.

I suppose there are two questions here:

1. Is there a way to prevent it from trying to update the key value?
2. if not how do I replicate the `ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues()` code that used to work fine in EF4?

**----UPDATE----**

My previous code I used for EF4 is as follows:

```
public static System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject ReAttach(this System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext obj, System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject objectDetached)
{
    if (objectDetached.EntityKey != null)
    {
        object original = null;
        if (obj.TryGetObjectByKey(objectDetached.EntityKey, out original))
        {
            objectDetached = obj.ApplyCurrentValues(objectDetached.EntityKey.EntitySetName, objectDetached);
            return objectDetached;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return objectDetached;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would interest me how your corresponding code with EF 4 and `ObjectContext` exactly looked like. Also with `ObjectContext` you would either get the same exception or you would update another entity than `currentObject` (see my answer below). I don't know how an Update procedure like the one you are trying in your question could have worked with `ObjectContext`.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this exception indicates that something is wrong - or at least unusual - in your calling code.

`currentObject` is an attached entity while `sourceObject` is (normally) a detached object (not necessarily an entity) that should have the same key values (or no key properties at all).

Indeed setting the current values works differently with `DbContext` because you have to supply the current attached entity explicitly in order to update its current values. Using `ApplyCurrentValues` of `ObjectContext` you don't supply this entity:

```
objectContext.ApplyCurrentValues("MyEntitySet", sourceObject);
```

This is different because...

- `sourceObject` must be an entity and cannot be an arbitrary `object`
- it updates the values of the attached entity that has the same key values as `sourceObject`

In your example it would update another entity than `currentObject` because apparently `currentObject` is not the entity that has the same key as `sourceObject`.

If you have used `ObjectStateEntry.ApplyCurrentChanges` (which is closer to the new version in `DbContext`) you would get the same exception:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)obj).ObjectContext;

var entry = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(currentObject);
entry.ApplyCurrentValues(sourceObject);
```

EF will complain here that you try to change the key values. And it will complain if `sourceObject` is not of the same type as `currentObject` while `DbContext` would allow that (which makes the procedure with `DbContext` more useful in my opinion because you can use arbitrary objects with matching property names - for example DTOs - to update the entity).

**Edit**

The main problem to reproduce the method you have used with EF 4 is that entities with EF 5/`DbContext` don't derive from `EntityObject` but are POCOs. Because of this you don't have an `EntityKey` available that would allow a generic implementation of this method.

What you could do is to introduce an interface that marks the key property of your entities, like so for example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your entity classes would implement this interface, for instance an `Order` entity:

```
public class Order : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShippingDate { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

You could create a generic method with a constraint for this interface:

```
public static T ReAttach<T>(DbContext context, T objectDetached)
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    T original = context.Set<T>().Find(objectDetached.Id);
    if (original == null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException();

    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(objectDetached);

    return objectDetached;
}
```

If your entities do not always have an `int` property `Id` but their keys have different types, names or could be composite it is probably the easier way to pass in the entity's key into the method instead of using an interface:

```
public static T ReAttach<T>(DbContext context, T objectDetached,
    params object[] keyValues) where T : class
{
    T original = context.Set<T>().Find(keyValues);
    if (original == null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException();

    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(objectDetached);

    return objectDetached;
}
```

Comment: Ok, well in that case perhaps my question should be "What is the EF5 equivalent to objectContext.ApplyCurrentValues()?" Although that exact question is what led to the code I have now.... Basically instead of having to explicitly update each value manually, I would love to be able to update all the values (apart from the key values) with one method call. Obviously this is exactly what ApplyCurrentValues() let me do in EF4.

Comment: @coolblue2000: No, it's not what `ApplyCurrentValues` does. That was the point of "*In your example it would update another entity than currentObject*" and therefore my comment question under your question. It's not clear to me how your code looked like in the past.

Comment: Ok, I have now updated my question with the codeI have been using very successfully in Entity Framework 4. I would like to replicate this in EF5.

Comment: Why there would be anything wrong in the calling code? For example if you are importing data from external source that does not have same key or none at all (say .csv) and match it with an entity by other properties. You *know* this is the new data you want for *that* entity but you are unable to set it because key of entity from .csv has default value.