# Generic Clone of EF6 Entity

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to get a generic CloneEntity function working with EF6.0.2

```
public static T CopyEntity<T>(MyContext ctx, T entity, 
bool copyKeys = false) where T : EntityObject
{
T clone = ctx.CreateObject<T>();
PropertyInfo[] pis = entity.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)
{
    EdmScalarPropertyAttribute[] attrs = (EdmScalarPropertyAttribute[])
                  pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute), false);

    foreach (EdmScalarPropertyAttribute attr in attrs)
    {
        if (!copyKeys && attr.EntityKeyProperty)
            continue;

        pi.SetValue(clone, pi.GetValue(entity, null), null);
    }
}

return clone;
}
```

[This code comes from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474296/Clone-an-Entity-in-Entity-Framework-4)

[update]
I had to change the declaration to

```
public static T CloneEntity<T>(T entity, bool copyKeys = false) where T : class
```

This solved a compile error : 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

However when I use this method no properties are copied to the new object.

I aren't using code first. The object I am using with it has been generated from the edmx file.

The kind of object I am using it with is generated from T4

```
public partial class job
{
    public short LineID { get; set; }
    public short CycleID { get; set; }
    // other fields 
}
```

My DBContext is like

```
public partial class DataEntities : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

[Update]

I tried

```
using (var db = CreateDb())
{

    var nJob = new job();
    db.jobs.Attach(nJob);
    db.Entry(nJob).CurrentValues.SetValues(job);

    return nJob;
}
```

but I get an error

```
"The property 'JobID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "
```

The context is a partial class

there is also

```
partial class DataEntities
{
    public DataEntities(string efConnectString)
        : base(efConnectString)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the object you're using it with

Comment: I'm guessing the partial keyword is throwing it off. Can you make sure that each definition of the type you're using inherits from EntityObject?

Comment: Here they talk about your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451120/the-type-must-be-a-reference-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t-in-the-gen

Comment: @Kevin the Entities are generated from T4 are you suggesting I alter the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they give you one out of the box.  Try something like:

```
context.Entry(MyNewEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(MyOldEntity);
```

Comment: nice, but i still have a problem. I updated the question to describe.

Comment: I solved the problem with the key by setting it to the old value first.
The issue is discussed at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646922/how-to-stop-dbentityentry-currentvalues-setvalues-trying-to-change-entitykey-val` 

Not generic, but good enough

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EntityHelper
{
    public static T CopyEntity<T>(MCEntities ctx, T entity, bool copyKeys = false) where T : class, new()
    {
        T clone = new T();
        var en = ctx.Entry(clone);
        en.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        ctx.Entry(clone).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        en.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ MAD Hello ! Your code works to copy an entity without childs collection. what changes should I make in order to copy one ( ore some ) childs collection and to attach to new object ? Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

I thought I would add my contribution to this. It is a VB implementation, and an addition to existing code found on code project.

This implementation allows for the relational properties to be included (but you have to specify this).

```
Imports System.Data.Objects
Imports System.Data.Objects.DataClasses
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices


Public Module Entities

''' <summary>
''' Clone an entity
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' Inspiration from: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474296/Clone-an-Entity-in-Entity-Framework-4
''' </remarks>
<Extension()>
Public Function CloneEntity(Of T As Class)(entity As T, context As ObjectContext, Optional include As List(Of IncludeEntity) = Nothing, Optional copyKeys As Boolean = False) As T
    Return CloneEntityHelper(entity, context, include, copyKeys)
End Function

Private Function CloneEntityHelper(Of T As Class)(entity As T, context As ObjectContext, Optional include As List(Of IncludeEntity) = Nothing, Optional copyKeys As Boolean = False) As T
    ' Set default parameter values
    If include Is Nothing Then include = New List(Of IncludeEntity)()
    'If visited Is Nothing Then visited = New List(Of String)()

    ' Get the type of entity we are dealing with
    Dim myType = entity.GetType()

    ' Make a copy of this object
    Dim methodInfo = context.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObject").MakeGenericMethod(myType)
    Dim result = methodInfo.Invoke(context, Nothing)

    ' Get the property information for the source object
    Dim propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperties()

    ' Copy over the property information
    For Each info In propertyInfo
        Dim attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute), False).ToList()

        For Each attr As EdmScalarPropertyAttribute In attributes 
            If (Not copyKeys) AndAlso attr.EntityKeyProperty
                Continue For
            End If

            info.SetValue(result, info.GetValue(entity, Nothing), Nothing)
        Next

        ' Handle relational properties
        If info.PropertyType.Name.Equals("EntityCollection`1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            ' Determine whether or not we are allowed to deal with this relationship
            Dim shouldInclude = include.SingleOrDefault(Function(i) i.Name.Equals(info.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            If shouldInclude Is Nothing Then Continue For

            ' Clone the property
            Dim relatedChildren = info.GetValue(entity, Nothing)

            ' Get an EntityCollection instance to hold the relational entries
            Dim propertyType As Type = relatedChildren.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First()
            Dim genericType As Type = GetType(EntityCollection(Of ))
            Dim boundType = genericType.MakeGenericType(propertyType)
            Dim children = Activator.CreateInstance(boundType)

            ' Load the children into the property
            For Each child In relatedChildren
                Dim cloneChild = CloneEntityHelper(child, context, shouldInclude.Children, shouldInclude.CopyKeys)
                children.Add(cloneChild)
            Next

            ' Save this value
            info.SetValue(result, children, Nothing)
        End If
    Next

    Return result
End Function


''' <summary>
''' Represent which (relational) properties should be included
''' </summary>
Public Class IncludeEntity
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Name of the relationship to include
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Name As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Relationships to include from the selected property
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Children As New List(Of IncludeEntity)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Whether or not to Copy keys
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property CopyKeys As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Empty Constructor
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create with single children
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New(propertyName As String, ParamArray childNodes() As String)
        Name = propertyName 
        Children = childNodes.Select(Function(n) new IncludeEntity(n)).ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

and an example usage:

```
Dim formToClone = con.SF_Forms.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.Form_id = f.Id)

' Define what should be copied
Dim inc = New List(Of IncludeEntity)()

Dim validation = New IncludeEntity("SF_Questions_validation", "SF_Validation_Parameters")

Dim questions = new IncludeEntity("SF_Questions", "SF_Question_Parameters")
questions.Children.Add(validation)

Dim questionGroups = new IncludeEntity("SF_Question_Groups")
questionGroups.Children.Add(questions)

Dim actions = New IncludeEntity("SF_Actions", "SF_Action_Parameters")

inc.Add(questionGroups)
inc.Add(actions)
inc.Add(new IncludeEntity("SF_Messages"))

' Save the cloned form
Dim clonedForm = formToClone.CloneEntity(con, include := inc)
```

It took me a while to work out how to do the relational aspect, so hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Hi alex. I'm not sure, I haven't tried. Give it a whirl and let me know.

Comment: Please , if you can , I posted a question using your code and the problems I have : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598831/entity-framework-why-this-code-doesnt-work/29600726?noredirect=1#comment47365672_29600726.  Can you give an opinion if you can ? thank you !